# Web Components conversion happens too late

Tags: javascript, interpolation, web-component

In the following (reduced) code the first Tester instance uses a predefined template whereas the second one uses a directly coded one. The interpolation works for the second one since the html contains the proper HTML code. The first Tester instance still has the innerHTML of <test-component> during the time of the interpolation. How can I change the code concept to also interpolate the first example?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Web Components Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tc"></div>
    <div id="tc2"></div>
    <script>
        class TestComponent extends HTMLElement {
            constructor () {
                super();
                this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
                this.shadowRoot.appendChild(this.createTemplate().content.cloneNode(true));
            }
            createTemplate () {
                const template = document.createElement("template");
                template.innerHTML = "<h1>{{title}}</h1><p>{{text}}</p>";
                return template;
            }
        }
        window.customElements.define("test-component", TestComponent);

        class Tester {
            constructor ({selector, stuff, template}) {
                this.selector = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
                this.template = template || null;
                this.stuff = stuff;
                this.render();
                this.interpolate();
            }
            render () {
                this.selector.forEach(s => {if (this.template) s.innerHTML = this.template});
            }
            interpolate () {
                this.selector.forEach(s => {
                    for (let key in this.stuff) { 
                        const regex = new RegExp(`{{ *${key} *}}`, "g");       
                        s.innerHTML = s.innerHTML.replace(regex, this.stuff[key]);;
                    } 
                });
            }
        }

        new Tester ({
            selector: "#tc",
            stuff: {title: "Test Title", text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"},
            template: "<test-component>"
        });

        new Tester ({
            selector: "#tc2",
            stuff: {title: "Title that works", text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"},
            template: "<h1>{{title}}</h1><p>{{text}}</p>"
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is:

```
s.innerHTML = s.innerHTML.replace(regex, this.stuff[key]);
```

`s` is the outer DIV, not the `<test-component>` innerHTML

effectively ***destroying and re-creating*** `<test-component>` **for every key**

Thus the `constructor()` always sets your default template as (element) innerHTML again:

### console logs on your code running on the first example:

[image]

### Note

```
constructor () {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});       
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(this.createTemplate().content.cloneNode(true));
}
createTemplate () {
    const template = document.createElement("template");
    template.innerHTML = "<h1>{{title}}</h1><p>{{text}}</p>";
    return template;
}
```

is a bit bloated: You are creating **HTML** inside a Template, then ***adding*** the **cloned** content of the Template (which is: **HTML**) to the ***empty*** shadowRoot innerHTML

```
constructor () {
    super() // returns 'this'
       .attachShadow({mode: "open"}) // returns shadowRoot
       .innerHTML = "<h1>{{title}}</h1><p>{{text}}</p>";
}
```

You only have to clone (Templates) when you need to re-use the original (Templates)

## Solution: move {{}} parsing inside the element

```html
<test-component id=One></test-component>
<test-component id=Two></test-component>
<script>
  window.customElements.define("test-component", class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super().attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
      this.setTemplate(`<b>{{title}}</b> {{text}}`);
    }
    setTemplate(html, data = {}) {
      this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = html;
      this.parse(data);
    }
    parse(data) {
      let html = this.shadowRoot.innerHTML;
      for (let key in data) {
        const regex = new RegExp(`{{${key}}}`, "g");
        html = html.replace(regex, data[key]);
      }
      this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = html;
    }
  });
  One.parse({
    title: "Test Title",
    text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
  })
  Two.setTemplate('<h4>{{title}}<h4>{{subtitle}}', {
    title: "Test Two",
    subtitle: "a Sub title"
  })
  let Three = document.createElement('test-component');
  Three.parse({//parsed IN shadowDOM innerHTML!
    title: "Title Three",
    text: "text three"
  })
  document.body.append(Three)
</script>
```

Comment: If I wanted to access the components HTML, how could I do that? Is there a way to parse the component from another object?

Comment: with ``mode:"open"`` the shadowDOM is... open... and the content is ``document.querySelector(...).shadowRoot.innerHTML``